# One of threads stop responding

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I have a process that I need to watch in daemon thread, but when first of both do Thread.sleep() it stops. For example:

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(argsList);
        pb.directory(new File("path"));
        Process process = pb.start();
        new ProcessListenerDaemon(clientName, username, process).start();
```

So, ProcessListenerDaemon has delay in run()

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try{;
        while(isProcessAlive()){
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME * 1000);
            doSomethisng();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It the delay is too long (20 seconds, for example) it won't wake up, if it will be too short (1 second) it will work fine but Process will hangs (probably it calls Thread.sleep())
What is the problem?

Comment: Not enough information there to answer your question. What does your main thread do after starting the ProcessListenerDaemon? What is done in isProcessAlive() method? in doSomething()? My guess is that one of these methods is hanging, not your sleep() method.

Comment: I can see you are starting 2 threads, ProcessBuilder starts a process in thread and the ProcessListenerDaemon. Can you please provide the code of ProcessBuilder and what you are checking in isProcessAlive(). You can have issues if you your isProcessAlive() does not properly send signal to terminate the loop.

Comment: I used System.out.println() to trace execution of my code and code after Thread.sleep() didn't executed. isProcessAlive() only check process.exitValue(). Also, main thread is SwingWorker, and after starting ProcessListenerDaemon it dispose JFrame, but even if i remove dispose() it doesn't work. isProcessAlive() working properly, as I wrote, if delay is short ProcessListenerDaemon working fine, except that process it listen to is not responding.

Comment: We need to see the code for `ProcessListenerDaemon`, in particular the code in its `start` method.  You say "if delay is short ProcessListenerDaemon working fine, except that process it listen to is not responding."  That "except" means it is not working fine, I think - it is interrupting the Process you are trying to silently monitor.  Somehow - the delay in `ProcessListenerDaemon` is blocking your `Process` object called `process`.  Without the code for `ProcessListenerDaemon`, we can't help you with how.

Answer (score 1):

Would be very difficult to diagnose the problem only with the information you are providing, however, I can tell that my first rule about multithreading is: Never use time to synchronize threads. You'll never know if the sentence after start() will be executed when the second thread is created or if the thread will be already finished. When I need to run two threads, and want to make sure the new thread is available after the next sentence in my main thread is executed, I use a code similar to this:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      lock.notify();
    }
    ...
}});

t2.start();
synchronized (lock) {
    try {
        lock.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Thread was interrupted before it started
        ...
    }
}
... your t2 thread is running
```

Second: Never use the System.exit() method, it will kill your program.

Comment: Here time is not for synchronization, it is only delay. `process` is not my application and I can not modify it. `System.exit()` here for killing program.